# Разложение числа на множители. Не ясно зачем ведется одна проверка

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть код на C# разложения числа на множители. Понимаю весь код, кроме строчки:

> ```
> if (n / b * b - n == 0)
> ```

**Что проверяет данная строчка? Ведь  пы просто получаем ноль, зачем тогда она нужна?**

```
using System;

namespace ExpandNumberForum
{
  class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = string.Empty;
        int b, c, n;

        Console.WriteLine("Input number: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n)) return;

        while ((n % 2) == 0)
        {
            n = n / 2;
            s += "2*";
        }
        b = 3; c = (int)Math.Sqrt(n) + 1;
        while (b < c)
        {
            if ((n % b) == 0)
            {
                if (n / b * b - n == 0)
                {
                    s += b.ToString() + "*";
                    n = n / b;
                    c = (int)Math.Sqrt(n) + 1;
                }
                else
                    b += 2;
            }
            else
                b += 2;
        }
        s += n.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Деление не простое) Целочисленное.

Comment: `n / b * b - n = n - n%b - n = -n%b`, где знак не имеет смысла в контесте сравнения с нулём.

Answer (score 5):

Эта строчка проверяет, что `n` нацело делится на `b`.

То есть делает то же самое, что `(n % b) == 0`.

`if` с проверкой `n / b * b - n == 0` - лишний.

```js
function dividers(n) {
  var s = [];
  var b;
  var c;

  while ((n % 2) == 0) {
    n = n / 2;
    s.push(2);
  }
  b = 3;
  c = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)) + 1;
  while (b < c) {
    if ((n % b) == 0) {
      s.push(b);
      n = n / b;
      c = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)) + 1;
    } else
      b += 2;
  }
  s.push(n);
  return s;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(dividers(621756)));
```

Comment: можно ведь ее заменить на `n%b==0`?

Comment: @INTOTHESPACE вполне

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `/` выполняет *целочисленное* деление, т.е. деление с остатком, c округлением частного к нулю до целого. По этой причине в общем случае `a / b * b` не равно `a`. Равенство будет выполняться только в том случае, если `a` нацело делится на `b`.

В "студенческом" коде часто встречается использование следующей техники вычисления остатка `r` от деления `a` на `b`

```
r = a - a / b * b
```

(до того, как студентам расскажут про существование оператора `%`, а также и после).

Именно это вы и видите в данном коде. Проверка `n / b * b - n == 0` - это проверка того, что остаток от деления `n` на `b` равен `0`, т.е. того, что `n` нацело делится на `b`. Эквивалентно можно было написать `n / b * b == n`, но лучше, конечно, воспользоваться оператором `%` и просто проверить `n % b == 0`.

---

Как правильно заметил @Igor в своем ответе, проверять `n / b * b - n == 0` после уже выполненной эквивалентной проверки `n % b == 0` - совершенно бессмысленный шаг.